# I can't see apk on android phone

Tags: android

The error show me, I can't use apk and can't display apk on phone screen.

```
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] ------------------------------
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] Android Launch!
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] adb is running normally.
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] No Launcher activity found!
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
    [2015-04-01 16:53:46 - Bus] Performing sync
    [2015-04-01 16:53:49 - Bus] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
    [2015-04-01 16:53:49 - Bus] \Bus\bin\Bus.apk installed on device
    [2015-04-01 16:53:49 - Bus] Done!
```

Comment: this logcat shows your app is already installed in device,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

For example:

```
<activity
        android:name="main.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```